# Javascript variable protection

Tags: javascript, php, variables, sanitization

Is it possible to protect Javascript variables gotton from PHP variables? If so, how?

```
 this.name = "<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>";
```

I don't want users to change their names. I've read something about sanitizing, but don't know what it is, and I don't know if this would work with this setup. Thanks.

Comment: As soon as it hits the browser, consider nothing protected.

Answer (score 1):

`this.name` is a property, not a variable strictly speaking. This means you can get a basic level of protection with `Object.defineProperty`.

For example, the following will set the property to read-only (so that attempts to set it to another value will fail).

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
    value: "<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>",
    writable: false
});
```

It's important to note that this largely just protects against accidental manipulation. As a client-side language, any determined person will be able to manipulate your code and values and there's nothing you can do to prevent this.